# can we set pre text in the spinner in android

Tags: android

I am getting all the values from the webservice. Can we set this value by default in my spinner.like pre populated value for update.

we do like that `edittext1.setText("");`
So can we do same it for spinner.

please help me for this.

Thnak you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no its not possible in spinner. you can't set a title like value in spinner in starting.We have use ArrayAdaper then it will show value that is selected.

Like Spinner.setSelection(position);

**Edited to insert data in spinner**

Call these code whenever you want to change content of Spinner
first find it by id

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.unique_id );
```

and then place this code where ever you want to update spinner data

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(

this, R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_drop_down_item );
s.setAdapter( adapter );
```

R.array.array_name is array store in String file in res.you can use your dynamic array too

Comment: yaa that is ok,but I want that sombody wants to update his data  so when click of update then all the data will fill.so what should i do for it.